# Check whether a directed, rooted spanning tree is actually some shortest-paths tree in $O(V + E)$ time

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

Given a directed graph $G = (V, E)$, with all edge weights being non-negative, someone has written a program that he/she claims implements Dijkstra's algorithm.
For a fixed starting vertex $s$, the program produces $v.d$ (*shortest distance from* $s$) and $v.\pi$ (*immediate predecessor in the shortest path*) for each vertex $v \in V$.

> **Question:** How to check whether the $d$ and $\pi$ values match those of some shortest-paths tree of $G$ in linear time (i.e., $O(V + E)$)?

---

*My attempts:*

1. Feed the $d$ and $\pi$ values into a running instance of our *real* Dijkstra algorithm and check if some step would go wrong.
   The key point here is how to reduce the running time of the *real* Dijkstra algorithm from $O(E \log V)$ to $O(V + E)$, taking advantage of the existing $v.d$ and $v.\pi$ values.
2. To check the triangle inequality condition: For all edges $(u,v) \in E$, we have $d(s,v) \le d(s,u) + w(u,v)$.

   > **Question:** However, is the triangle inequality condition a sufficient one for some directed, rooted spanning tree to be a shortest-paths tree?

Comment: As per the discussion after my answer below, we should remove the path part $v.\pi$ and check only if $v.d$ is correct. That will be a much better question.

Comment: @randomA I am not sure about this idea. Maybe you can explain it more clearly in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: It is not actually an idea about solving the new problem that you just clarified to me though. I misread your question so I answered another understanding of your question.

Comment: This is a standard exercise.  We're not here to do your exercises for you.  I think you should put in more effort on your own.  Hint: I recommend you try some examples.  Try some example graphs, run Dijkstra's (a correct version), look at the $d$ and $\pi$ values, and look for patterns.  If $(u,v) \in E$, what can you say about the relationship between $d(s,v)$ and $d(s,u) + w(u,v)$?  Do you notice any patterns in your examples?  Now try to prove those patterns always hold.  I think you'll find that if you give this a try, you should soon be able to make some progress on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

1. This question is telling us to find an algorithm in $O(V+E)$ which immediately suggests us some kind of search in the graph, i.e, DFS.
2. Using $\pi$ we should be able to build a candidate tree $T$ rooted in $s$ to test if it's shortest-path tree.
3. In each shortest-path tree, we have that for every $v \in V(T)$, $v \neq s$, the equality $d(\pi(v)) + w(\pi(v), v) = d(v)$ holds.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove this in a similar way to how you prove [Bellman-Ford has converged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness). Let $d(v)$ be the distance from root to $v$ in this rooted spanning tree and let $\delta(v)$ be the shortest distance from $s$ to $v$ in the graph. If $d(v) = \delta(v)$, then attempting to relax all edges in $E$ should not change anything. When I say "relax" I mean, invoke the triangle inequality:

```
relax(u, v):
  if d(v) > d(u) + w(u,v):
    d(v) = d(u) + w(u,v)
    pi(v) = u
```

If, at any point, a relaxation changes $d(v)$, then clearly the spanning tree path is not the shortest. This makes sense intuitively, but we can prove it formally.

**Claim**: If $d(v) > \delta(v)$ for some node $v$, then some node $v'$ on the true shortest path from $s$ to $v$ has value $d(v')$ such that $d(v') > d(u) + w(u,v')$ for some edge $(u,v') \in E$.

**Proof**: By induction on the number of nodes $n$ in the shortest path from $s$ to $v$.

**Base Case**: When we have $n = 2$, then we have one edge in the shortest path $s \rightarrow v$. Thus, the true shortest path has distance $w(s,v)$. If $d(v) > \delta(v)$ then:

$$\begin{align*}
d(v) &> \delta(v)\\
& = w(s,v)\\
& = d(s) + w(s,v)
\end{align*}$$

**Inductive Case**: Assume the claim holds for the first $n-1$ nodes on the shortest path $\{s, u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_{n-2}, v\}$. We now prove it holds for the addition of $v$ to the shortest path.

If the claim holds for this whole path, then either some node prior to $v$ in the path triggers the if condition, and the claim holds by induction. Otherwise, we have for all nodes $u$ prior to $v$ that $d(u) = \delta(u)$ and $d(v) > \delta(v)$. Now we need only prove that $d(v) > d(u_{n-2}) + w(u_{n-2}, v)$:

$$\begin{align*}
d(v) &> \delta(v)\\
& = \delta(u_{n-2}) + w(u_{n-2}, v) & \text{by construction of the shortest path}\\
& = d(u_{n-2}) + w(u_{n-2}, v) \quad \square
\end{align*}$$

Thus, after running the relaxation step on all edges, you should have your answer.